# Determining the groups compatible with given fusion rules

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Say I have an unknown group $G$ with a simple, real, faithful representation $\mathbf n$ such that 
$$ {\mathbf n}\otimes{\mathbf n} \approx {\mathbf 1}_s\oplus{\mathbf a}_s\oplus{\mathbf b}_s\oplus{\mathbf c}_a$$
for simple representations $\bf a$, $\bf b$, and $\bf c$ of known dimensions. How can I find groups $G$ with this property? Under what conditions can such a group exist?

Comment: If you only had two nontrivial summands, or even if you knew that one of the trivial summands was again n, then I could answer your question. But this question is just beyond the techniques I know.

Comment: For the special case where ${\bf a}\approx {\bf n}$ what are you able to say? I know the fundamental of $S^{n+1}$ works (and obviously so does $\mathbb Z_2 \times S^{n+1}$), are there other examples?

Comment: Also the highly transitive subgroups of symmetric groups (alternating and Mathieau) plus G2 (and possibly highly transitive subgroups of G2, but I don't know if someone's worked out that classification for G2).

Comment: The main techniques for that case with the argument I have in mind are in Morrison-Penneys-S. https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06869, but you need to do some nontrivial additional work beyond what's there.  This is more a "I'm confident I could advise a grad student through this question" situation than a "I could explain to you exactly what the answer is and how to do it" situation.

Comment: My techniques also work for braided tensor categories, since groups are such a special case there may be group-specific techniques that work better.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I'm confused though about $\mathsf{Rep}(S^n)$, as this seems to contradict Corollary 8.9 unless I've misunderstanding something.

Comment: $S_n$ isn't "trivalent" because it is not generated by the trivalent vertex.  Instead it has a trivalent subcategory, which must have smaller 4-box space, and hence must be quantum SO_3.  You can then use an additional argument (not yet in print, though half of it appears in these notes (http://pages.iu.edu/~nsnyder1/macalaster.pdf) to show that the category generated by the trivalent vertex *and* the crossing has to be Deligne's $S_t$.

Comment: One final question, $G_2$ has the fusion rule ${\bf 7}\otimes{\bf 7}\rightarrow {\bf 1}_s + {\bf 28}_s+{\bf 7}_a+{\bf 14}_a$ so the trivalent vertex is antisymmetric not symmetric. Is this what you mean, or is there some clever way to fix this so that the vertex is symmetric?

Comment: Ah, sorry that's my mistake, I hadn't understood your subscripts.  Yes, for $G_2$ the copy of the $7$-dimensional is anti-symmetric, there's no clever way to change that.  So depending on which factor is $n$ you're either in the symmetric group (and friends) case or the $G_2$ (and friends) case.